# MFC: How can you change the height of the CEdit used on a CTreeView to change the label?

Tags: winapi, mfc, treeview

I have a `CTreeView` where the height of the items are taller because it's using an Icon that is about 24x24.  When I edit a label on the selected item it looks dumb because the selection is sticking out of both sides of the `CEdit` box.  I wanted to change the `CEdit` height, but if set during the `OnTvnBeginlabeledit()` it doesn't end up that way once the `CEdit` is shown.  How can I set the height?  If I have to subclass, how do I do that to an existing `CTreeView` ?

TIA!!

Comment: You can use `TVM_GETEDITCONTROL` to get the edit control handle to sub-class it. You'd need to override `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` I guess. Edit controls don't center their text vertically though so I think if you changed its height it might still look "dumb".

Comment: Well it has the `GetEditControl()` so I guess I can get that for the handle, and you're telling me to simply use the old school subclassing through the handle, not creating a C++ subclass of `CEdit` ?

Comment: Correct, you'll need to subclass the existing edit control.